# How to center the title for a two-column article?

Tags: titles, two-column

I'm trying to make an article and I want the title to be centered like the abstract. I have this for now:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{abstract} % Allows abstract customization

\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows customization of titles
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}} % Roman numerals for the sections
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\roman{subsection}} % roman numerals for subsections
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\centering}{\thesection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{}


\title{}
\author{Daniela Dur\'an Escalona}
\date{December , 2020}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\twocolumn[
  \begin{onecolabstract}
    hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola
    
  \end{onecolabstract}
  
]
\section{hola 2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `\maketitle` was already using `\twocolumn`, so the second one was on the next page.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{abstract} % Allows abstract customization

\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows customization of titles
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}} % Roman numerals for the sections
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\roman{subsection}} % roman numerals for subsections
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\centering}{\thesection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{}


\title{}
\author{Daniela Dur\'an Escalona}
\date{December , 2020}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[
 \maketitle
  \begin{onecolabstract}
    hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola
    
  \end{onecolabstract}
  
]
\section{hola 2}

\end{document}
```